# Scraping numbers from HTML using Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my homework:

> In this assignment you will write a Python program similar to http://www.py4e.com/code3/urllink2.py. The program will use urllib to read the HTML from the data files below, and parse the data, extracting numbers and compute the sum of the numbers in the file.
>
> We provide two files for this assignment. One is a sample file where we give you the sum for your testing and the other is the actual data you need to process for the assignment.
>
> Sample data: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html (Sum=2553)
>
> Actual data: http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228869.html (Sum ends with 10)
>
> You do not need to save these files to your folder since your program will read the data directly from the URL. Note: Each student will have a distinct data url for the assignment - so only use your own data url for analysis.

I want to fix mine code as it is what I have learned so far. I am getting an error as a name

> urlib is not defined

.. if I play with imports than I have a problem with sockets.

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlib.request(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


sum=0
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    y=str(tag)
    x= re.findall("[0-9]+",y)
    for i in x:
        i=int(i)
        sum=sum+i
print(sum)
```

Comment: If I change it to from urllib.request import urlopen then I have got  module socket have no  attribute as AF_INET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo: you're having `urlib`, it should be `urllib`. The `context=ctx` isn't necessary:

```
import re
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html'
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228869.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
s = sum(int(td.text) for td in soup.select('td:last-child')[1:])

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
2410
```

EDIT: Running your script:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = urllib.request.urlopen('http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_228869.html').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

sum=0
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    y=str(tag)
    x= re.findall("[0-9]+",y)
    for i in x:
        i=int(i)
        sum=sum+i
print(sum)
```

Prints:

```
2410
```

Comment: hey, thank You for the answer, I changed it for double l and now I am receiving urllib have no attribute request...  if i won't be able to fix my code I will use one provided by You, but I would be more happy to use mine one

Comment: 3.7 ... I probably mixed up the imports then

Comment: now when i run it  it is 'socket' have no attribute 'AF_INET'

Comment: shiit... it confused me, and I have the socket program in the same folder and for some reason, it occurred an error... now it is all good, ty very much, how ever why if im running i command promp python smth.py the error is showing from the other file? That is wired!!

Answer (score 3):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urlopen(url,).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
numlist = list()
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    y = str(tag)
    num = re.findall('[0-9]+',y)
    numlist = numlist + num

sum = 0
for i in numlist:
    sum = sum + int(i)

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
import re

ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

url = input('Enter - ')
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

sum=0
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    y=str(tag)
    x= re.findall("[0-9]+",y)
    for i in x:
        i=int(i)
        sum=sum+i
print(sum)
```

Comment: this was the assignment on coursera and write like this one this will work definitely and the ans is 2386 for the file on url:  http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_521301.html